# HTML tags in flutter from API

Tags: html, flutter, dart

I need to show data on the flutter from the server which contents some HTML tags.

I used [flutter_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html#-readme-tab-). 
It is working when I write HTML tag in the source code.
But when I try to show text containing html tag from API, it is not working.All the tags are showing on the app.

```
    Widget textSection = Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:10,right:20,bottom:10,left:28),

  child: Html(
    data: """
      ${event.details} + <p> I am</p>


    """,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    linkStyle: const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.redAccent,
      decorationColor: Colors.redAccent,
      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
    ),
    onLinkTap: (url) {
      print("Opening $url...");
    },
    onImageTap: (src) {
      print(src);
    },
    customRender: (node, children) {
      if (node is dom.Element) {
        switch (node.localName) {
          case "custom_tag":
            return Column(children: children);
        }
      }
      return null;
    },
    customTextAlign: (dom.Node node) {
      if (node is dom.Element) {
        switch (node.localName) {
          case "p":
            return TextAlign.justify;
        }
      }
      return null;
    },
    customTextStyle: (dom.Node node, TextStyle baseStyle) {
      if (node is dom.Element) {
        switch (node.localName) {
          case "p":
            return baseStyle.merge(TextStyle(height: 2, fontSize: 20));
        }
      }
      return baseStyle;
    },
  ),
);
```

output: [image]

Answer (score 0):

please add below line into the Html tag

**useRichText: false**

Like:

```
      Html(
              """
      ${event.details} + <p> I am</p>


    """,
 useRichText: false,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    linkStyle: const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.redAccent,
      decorationColor: Colors.redAccent,
      decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
    ),)
```